# How do I install a manufactured stone surround on a zero clearance fireplace?

Tags: fireplace

We just installed a new Napoleon NZ3000 fireplace and are prepping the area to install manufactured stone around it.  I am concerned about how to install the stone to the metal firebox.  I am not sure if I should screw cement board directly to the metal firebox or just the lath on top of it.  I would appreciate any information given.  If you need any pictures or any other information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to overlap, the cement board could do it in a more continuous manner, making it easier to thinset the stone.

Usually its either/or with lath vs cement board.  Are you going to use both?

Properly secured board (8in OC) is sufficient for manufactured stone for a veneer and using thinset.  Thicker stone using a mortar might want the lath support.